# How to read and store bits within sequence of bytes ( array of Short ) in C for sending data over network

Tags: c, byte, bit-manipulation, sequence

I am a newbie for solving these kind of problems. I need to extract variable no of bits from a single short value.

Like If I have read something from an array and need to fill another array first reading the 10 bits from earlier read value , and then again 6 bits to another short.

Like:

```
 int pixelNo = 0;
 short pixelValue_part = pixels[pixelNo]; 
 // but here i need only 10 bits , in the second 
 // iteration i might need 4 bits and then so on so forth.
```

After reading these shorts in parts, I will have to put these parts into 
second array sequentially inorder to arrange all pixels in the sequence.

### Note :

The problem is of arranging all input pixel sequence in ascending ordered way.I have to arrange the pixels of each having size of 10 bits. For this reason I would need read first 10 bits of short.

### Edit:

---

|    |                                                                                    0,1    512,513  1024,1025   1536,1537    1,2,3  513,514,515  1025,1206,1027  1357,1538,1539
|**_*|*__*_*_**|___*|****_*__**|***_***|__*_*|__*_*___*|****_*__*_*__**

I have above array as input and I want to produce output like the following array.

---

|    |                                                                                    0,1    2,3  4,5   6,7  ......  513,514,515,1024,1025,1536,1537...
|**_*|*__*_*_**|___*|****_*__**|***_***|__*_*|__*_*___*|****_*__*_*__**

Values of arrays all are Pixels of some image. So in actual the image was unarranged in pixels in input array, and then the second array is the array of arranged (sorted ) pixels.

Comment: I don't understand the edit: what do the numbers mean?  Why do some numbers appear more than once?  What are the |__| sections supposed to be?  I thought you were extracting bits from a short?  And what is the relationship between pixels and bits?

Comment: I sort out myself that the solution was sorting but in unusual manner.
The no´s are the Pixels ( like 1 = 1st Pixel , 1025  = 1025th Pixel ).
and actually |_| are just array cells, but it was not being edited properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your original data is in `src`, and you want a span of `n` bits (starting `n+pos` bits from the low end), this will extract those bits:

```
(src >> pos) & ((1<<n)-1)
```

Breaking it down:

- `(1<<n)-1` is a mask of `n` 1's (binary)
- `src >> pos` slides the bits you want down to the "bottom" of the variable
- Then we bitwise-and the two together, effectively erasing the bits you don't want, leaving behind the ones you do

You can do this for each piece you need.  To put the pieces together, you'd use `<<` to shift pieces where you need them to be and then `|` (bitwise-or) the pieces together.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Scott. As I am totally new bie for these kind of scanarios, so kindly do a little more. I have edited the question for more specific stuff to handle